# C++ Design pattern for Search and Replace

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have big paragraph with some special characters as %1 , %2, %3

I need to know if there is any design pattern to replace those with proper values and create final paragraph.
For Example:
Following is my static paragraph.

%1 is beautiful country , %2 is the capital of %1, %1 national language is %3.

I get values of %1,%2, %3 by some source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `strstr` or `sscanf` to find string pointers to a semi-pattern(both are part of the c std library), how ever, to replace, you would need to expand the memory block to accommodate the replacements(if they are bigger), have a look at grep(for unix), or see some of the string search algo's, like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

You can also have a look at the [google template system](http://google-ctemplate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) or [pegtl](http://code.google.com/p/pegtl/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a design pattern for this, but it looks like you want to incorporate some templating into your application.

Example of templating with [jinja 2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/):

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> template = Template('{{ country }} is a beautiful country!')
>>> template.render(country='India')
India is a beautiful country.
```

Or just *search-and-replace* ...

Comment: answered Q before the title was changed to "C++ ..."; so feel free to downvote ..

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is building a parser.  For something as simple as your problem, you would probably want to keep the design simple and use the search-replace mechanism for strings available in most languages.

If you need something more powerful (for instance, to allow "%1" in the final string), I would look into using a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) or [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammars) engine, if this is something you plan on using in the real world, as dealing with edge cases (such as `%%1%1%%%1%`) can get quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C++ then you've a couple of choices for string formatting

1. [boost::string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1701549)
2. [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) (though this may not work exactly like you want it to.)
3. [std::string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) (can get messy)

Comment: Or just Boosts String Algorithms: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1701549

Comment: @gf, yes. I really do need to brush up on my boost sometime soon. Haven't used it in years.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your programming language really. In C# (.net) you could use:

```
var replaced = string.Format("{0} is a {1}", "klausbyskov", "donkey");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question completely. But I think you can look at how MessageFormat works in Java. Here is an example -

```
 int fileCount = 1273;
 String diskName = "MyDisk";
 Object[] testArgs = {new Long(fileCount), diskName};

 MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat(
     "The disk \"{1}\" contains {0} file(s).");

 System.out.println(form.format(testArgs));
```